# Reading Azure Blobs with Binary type in C#

Tags: c#, azure-blob-storage

I have below code where I am trying to return contents of the blobs. I am able to read file with DownloadTextAsync and return the contents but My code will fail if the blob is of binary type, so i would like to read the stream and then do a text reader method before returning the string. I am unable to achieve that, would like some advice to complete the following code. with the below code I get null value  in "recJson" with no error.

```
public async Task<Stream> DownloadBlob(string containerName, string fileName, string connectionString)
        {
            
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(connectionString))
            {
                connectionString = @"UseDevelopmentStorage=true";
                containerName = "testblobs";
            }
            var result = new MemoryStream();
            Microsoft.Azure.Storage.CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = Microsoft.Azure.Storage.CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString);
            CloudBlobClient serviceClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            CloudBlobContainer container = serviceClient.GetContainerReference(containerName);
            CloudBlockBlob blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(fileName);
            if (blob.Exists())
            {//DownloadAsync
                using (result = new MemoryStream())
                {

                   await blob.DownloadToStreamAsync(result);
                   var result1 = result.ToArray();
                   using var reader = new StreamReader(result);

                    var recJson = reader.ReadToEnd();

                }
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that, after downloading to the `MemoryStream`, the position of that stream is at the end, so there is nothing left for the `StreamReader` to read. Try `result.Position = 0;` before `reader.ReadToEnd();`

Comment: it says not activated in result